# Did Vishnu have some role in marriage of Shiva with Parvati or with Sati?

Tags: shiva, puranas, marriage, parvati

Parvati is the wife of Shiva. As far as I know , She was the one who asked and persuaded Shiva to marry her.
Vishnu is considered as the brother of Parvati.

Did VIshnu have some role in their marriage ? Was Vishnu the one who told Parvati about Shiva or something like that ?
Or Even with Sati.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scripture says Parvati is Vishnu's sister?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26748/which-scripture-says-parvati-is-vishnus-sister)

Answer (score 1):

For Mata Parvati's marriage all gods including Lord Vishnu prayed to Maa Parvati.:

**Sri Shiv Puran 2.3:3:4.:**

> The gods said:—
>
> 9. O Śivā, O great Goddess, O mother of the universe we gods bow to you, the destroyer of all distress.
> 10. O Goddess, neither the Vedas nor the sacred texts know you perfectly. Your greatness, O Śivā, is beyond the scope of speech and mind and cannot even be meditated upon.
> 11. Even the Vedas mention you, trembling with fright, by negating what you are not. What will be the matter in regard to others?
> 12. Many devotees know the same after getting your favour through devotion. There is no cause for fear to the devotees who seek refuge in you.
> 13. O great Goddess listen to our submission which we, your slaves for ever, are going to explain.
> 14. Formerly you were born as the daughter of Dakṣa and were married to Śiva. You destroyed the great misery of Brahmā and others.
> 15. Being disrespected by your father, you cast off your body in accordance with your vow. You then went to your own world and Śiva became miserable.
> 16. O great Goddess, the purpose of the gods has not been completely carried out. The sages are agitated. Hence we, Gods, have sought refuge in you.
> 17. O great Goddess, please fulfil the desire of the God, O Śivā, so that the words of Sanatkumāra may be fruitful.
> 18. O Goddess, incarnating again on the earth please be the wife of Rudra (Śiva) again. Carry on your sports in a fitting manner and let the Gods be happy.
> 19. O Goddess, may Rudra too, the resident of Kailāsa be happy. Let all become happy. Let misery perish entirely.
>
> Brahmā said:—
>
> 20. Saying so, Viṣṇu and the other gods, full of loving devotion remained waiting silently and humbly.

For Maa Sati's marriage all gods prayed to Lord Shiva.:

**Sri Shiva Purana 2.2:2:16.:**

> Brahmā said:—
>
> 45. On hearing these words of Śiva in the presence of Viṣṇu, smilingly and joyously I spoke thus in humble spirits.
> 46. O lord Śiva, I shall suggest such a woman as you desire for yourself,
> 47. She is Umā, O lord. Formerly she manifested herself in the forms of Sarasvatī and Lakṣmī in order to fulfil her task.
> 48. Lakṣmī became the wife of Viṣṇu and Sarasvatī mine. From her desire for the welfare of the world she has taken a third form.
> 49. She is born now as Dakṣa’s daughter in the name of Satī. O lord, she will be an ideal wife rendering wholesome service.
> 50. O lord of devas, at present she is performing penance for securing you. She is firm in her austere rites. She desires you as her husband. Indeed she is highly brilliant.
> 51. O Lord Śiva, be merciful to her. Grant her the desired boon. Then lovingly marry her.
> 52. O Śiva, this is the desire of Viṣṇu, the devas and mine too. With a benignant look fulfil our desire. Let us see the wedding festivities with devotion.
> 53. Let there be a happy and auspicious occasion (for that) in the three worlds. Let all ailments vanish. Let there be no doubt about it.
> 54. Then at the conclusion of my speech, Viṣṇu, the slayer of Madhu demon,[2] spoke to Śiva who assumes various forms during His divine sports and who is favourably disposed to his devotees.
>
> Viṣṇu said:—
>
> 55. O great lord, the lord of devas, O Śiva the merciful, there is no doubt in this that what Brahmā has said constitutes what I have to say.
> 56. Hence, O great lord be merciful to me and carry out this request. Marrying her please make the three worlds blessed with a leader with benignant look.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..